# Click image to advance

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to improve a thumbnail gallery by making it so one could click the main image to advance to the next image in the list. The main image is in the #image div. Right now you can only click the thumbnail (.image) to select an image. Below is how it is setup right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<ul class="thumb">

<li><a href="images/1.png" class="image"><img src="images/t1.png"border="0"/></a></li>
<li><a href="images/2.png" class="image"><img src="images/t2.png"border="0"/></a></li>

 <div id="container"><div id="image"></div> 
</div>



$(function() {
$(".image").click(function() {
var image = $(this).attr("href");

$('#image').hide();
$('#image').fadeIn();
$('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '">');  

return false;
    });
    (location.attr)? $("a [rel="+location.attr+"]").click():$(".thumb a:first").click();

});
```

Comment: Just a note, border styling, and all other styling, should be done in your CSS file to conform with W3C standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have malformed html. You are missing the closing `ul`. Not sure if that's a typo or not. Anyway, does this do what you want?

```
$("#image").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $thumbs = $(".thumb");
    var currentImage = $this.children("img").attr("src");

    // Find the next image in the list of thumbs
    var $next = $("a[href='" + currentImage + "']", $thumbs).closest("li").next().find("a");

    // If at the end of the list of thumbs, use the first
    if ($next.length < 1)
        $next = $("li:first a", $thumbs);

    var image = $next.attr("href");

    $this.hide();
    $this.fadeIn();
    $this.html('<img src="' + image + '">');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfvgyhn/PEgsT/6/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I havent been able to get it to work quite right. It now returns the smaller thumbnail in the #image div instead of the large one, when clicked. I think it has to do with the attr('src')...I have tried attr('hfref') but that doesnt seem to work.        Also if the second image is being displayed and that is clicked, it goes to the first image for some reason.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood what you wanted. See edits and updated demo for changes. When the last image is displayed in the list and it is clicked, it starts over at the first. That's why the second image goes back to the first. Would you rather it just stops changing when you got to the last image?

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, thanks so much! This is exactly what i was trying to figure out.  BTW, what does the ',' in the parenthesis do for like in:   $next = $("li:first a", $thumbs);   Does that mean that you are only referencing the li within the thumbs div?

Comment: Yep, the second arg is an optional context arg. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/. Also, if that works for you, make sure to remember to accept it as the answer.